# Is minimongo's findOne constant time for indexed fields?

Tags: meteor, minimongo

I know that findOne is constant time when using it in the following way:

```js
collection.findOne(aString)
```

However, I can't seem to find out if it's still constant time when querying an indexed field that isn't `_id`. For example, I have a collection that's mirroring an external API. In this collection, there's a separate `id` field that's indexed.

My question is, is `collection.findOne({ id: anId })` still constant time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. From the minimongo documentation: "Internally, all documents are mapped in a single JS object from _id to the document. Besides this mapping, Minimongo doesn't implement any types of secondary indexes."

Source: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/master/packages/minimongo

Answer (score 0):

There is only one index(primary) in minimongo and it is on _id

Comment: It would be nice to add some explanation to the OP's question: *Is `collection.findOne({ id: anId ])` still constant time?*